# Extract Json Data with Python

Tags: python, json

My Jason Data looks like this:

```
    {
    "componentId": "SD1:1100047938",
    "componentType": "Device",
    "name": "WR50MS15-7938 (WR 33)",
    "product": "SB 5000TL",
    "productTagId": 9037,
    "pvPower": 886,
    "serial": "1100047938",
    "specWhOutToday": 3.0909803921568626,
    "specWhOutYesterday": 2.924313725490196,
    "state": 307,
    "totWhOutToday": 15764,
    "totWhOutYesterday": 14914
}
```

How could i only extract:

- "state" to a separate file
- "pv-power" to a sperate file ?

Thanks !

Comment: What did you try? Do you know how to access keys and values from a Python dictionary?

Comment: You read the json into a variable and extract. We need example code to see where there is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json
import urllib3
import sys
import requests

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

fehler = '"state": 35'
urltoken = "https://172.16.63.100/api/v1/token"
urldaten = "https://172.16.63.100/api/v1/overview/Plant:1/devices?todayDate=2022-10-17T12%3A53%3A16.746Z"
urlaktuell = "https://172.16.63.100/api/v1/widgets/gauge/power?componentId=Plant%3A1&type=PvProduction"

data = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": "...",
    "password": "...",
}

response = requests.post(urltoken, data, verify=False)

#print(response.json())

data = json.loads(response.text)

with open('/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_DataManager/token.txt', 'w') as f:
    data = json.dump(data, f, indent = 2)

with open('/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_DataManager/token.txt') as json_file:
    data1 = json.load(json_file)

token = data1["access_token"]

payload={}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }

response = requests.request("GET", urldaten, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)


data = json.loads(response.text)

with open('/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_DataManager/info.txt', 'w') as f:
    data = json.dump(data, f, indent = 2)



if fehler in open('/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_DataManager/info.txt').read():
    print("Mindestens ein Wechselrichter hat einen Fehler!")
    exit(1)

else:
    print("Alle Wechselrichter Online!")
    exit(0)


payload={}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }

response = requests.request("GET", urlaktuell, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)

aktuell = json.loads(response.text)

daten = aktuell["value"]

print("Aktuelle Leistung:", 0.001*daten , "KWh")
```

I now managed to do all i wanted like this :)
Well at first it ignores all Certificate Warnings i have been getting from my SMA Monitoring Device.

Then it gathers the Bearer Access token an stores it into an .txt file

After this is sends a request for json data to urldaten and urlaktuell. This Data is then stored in info.txt and ertrag.txt :) In this Files it checks if there is a faulty Inverter stored :)

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Comment: Done ! Please read my explanation and Upvote if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    url = "https://172.16.63.100/api/v1/overview/Plant:1/devices?todayDate=2022-10-17T12%3A53%3A16.746Z"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2NjYwMTU0MzMsInN1YiI6Ik1iYWNobCIsInVpZCI6Ijc1YmNkNTM2LTFhOTYtNDQ4My05MjQxLWZkNjY5Zjk3M2Y5OCIsImV4cCI6MTY2NjAxOTAzM30.bMMAsD8iPrAXDp7fbnwYL3Y8lj4Ktok3tU9NHZkYq8s'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)

#print(response.text)

data = json.loads(response.text)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    data = json.dump(data, f, indent = 2)
```

This is my Code for gathering the JSON Data.

I need to exctract the above mentioned Values.

Comment: Hello, please update your question with the additional details. Post only an answer if it solves the problem. You can of course write an answer if you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After you run `data = json.loads(response.text)` , the json is loaded into your `data` variable as a python dictionary.
So `state = data.state` and `pvPower = data.pvPower` should give the info you're after.

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with that information, as far as extracting to a separate file. But, `json.dump()` does output data to a json file.